# Create derived class instance in base class

Tags: inheritance, c++-cli

Is there a way to create derived `class` instance from base `class`?

If I try code like this

```
public ref class Foo
    {
    static Bar^ Create () { return gcnew Bar (); }
    };

public ref class Bar : Foo {};
```

I get an error

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'

If I try to change places of those definitions:

```
public ref class Bar : Foo {};

public ref class Foo
    {
    static Bar^ Create () { return gcnew Bar (); }
    };
```

I get an error

> error C2504: 'Foo' : base class undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++/CLI compiler has the same restriction as the C++ compiler.  It is a single-pass compiler, all declarations must be known before they are used.   You'll have to jump through the same hoop you do in C++, you must write a *forward declaration*:

```
ref class Bar;              // Forward declaration

public ref class Foo
{
    static Bar^ Create();   // Can't be inline anymore
};

public ref class Bar : Foo {};
```

Okay now, all definitions are available:

```
Bar^ Foo::Create() {
    return gcnew Bar; 
}
```

Fwiw: nothing is lost from not being able to define the Create() function inline anymore.  It is the job of the jitter to inline code and will always inline small methods like Create().

Comment: So there is no way to get this with inline methods?

Comment: As I noted, never fret about inlining methods, it is irrelevant in C++/CLI code.  Irrelevant in C++ code as well btw, modern optimizers completely ignore inlining hints.

Comment: I just like when all of the methods are either inline or on separete `cpp` file (easyer to search). I guess I'll either have to move all methods out or make an exception.